# Delay Flyout Menu using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu built on jQuery and built it following a [tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/16/slide-down-box-menu/). I would like to add a delay when the mouse leaves the menu for better user experience. I can get the menu to delay using jQuery `delay` and it works very well with one exception, the fly out drop down menus.

Due to the length of code I have a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/6nKeM/4/) with the code. The flyout menu I am referring to contains the words `Website` `Illustrations` and `Photography`.

How do I delay the flyout so it closes when the menu does vs disappearing immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Here is another take on it:
```

[**jSFIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aaaheatair/Bsybs/1/)

Comment: I like that adaption. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [doTimeout](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/hoverintent/) jQuery plug-in is perfect for what you're wanting to do.

[Check out these examples](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/hoverintent/).

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/46We5/1/)

What was this:

```
$jsub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');
```

is now changed to this:

```
$jsub_menu.delay(100).animate({'left':'0px'},100).hide('100');
```